# Drupal error PDOException SQLState[22007] 'invalid datetime format' in MoneySuite PayPerView

Tags: drupal, pay-per-view

On pay-per-view content nodes (with Drupal MoneySuite module) when I click 'override settings' to input an amount/ type for then node it crashes with this error, though I have tried many versions for the price (eg 1, or 1.00) and dates (eg 2, or 2 days). I have tried using full html, filtered html and plain text in the settings for the field. One answer on Stackexhange hints that this is a ut8 issue but I don't know what that means about how to solve it?  Any tips?

The error is:

```
     PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect     integer value: 'full_html' for column 'protected_content_message_format' at row 1: INSERT INTO {ms_ppv_price} (vid, nid, price, expiration_string, allow_multiple, protected_content_message, protected_content_message_format, stock, out_of_stock_message) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 96 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 96 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 3 days [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => This is a premium film- pay per view only. Get access [ms_ppv:price] to view for [ms_ppv:expirationLength] : [ms_ppv:addToCartLink] [ms_ppv:nodeTeaser] [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => full_html [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => ) in ms_ppv_insert_node_price() (line 774 of /home/cineafzh/public_html/sites/all/modules/moneysuite/ms_ppv/ms_ppv.module).
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the MoneySuite module created the database table incorrectly.

Your error message explains exactly what's going wrong.

Column 'protected_content_message_format' is defined as a datetime column in your database. The value the module attempts to store in it is 'full_html', which is a string. It fails validation and throws an exception.

One workaround would be to edit your database and change the type of column for 'protected_content_message_format' to string, instead of datetime.

I can't guarantee that this won't introduce other undesirable behaviour without looking at the code, but it would definitely resolve this specific error.

Comment: thank you so much @KarlBuys, Good thinking. I had created a few content types for pay per view using MoneySuite. I found with another content type (created using the same module) this error message didn't arise. So I'm using that as a workaround. I guess that might be evidence in this case it is not the database table that is the issue? (I am a beginner though, so not sure).

Comment: Looking at [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) indicates that datetime accepts input in the following range: '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'.

Comment: Sorry, meant to include this in the previous comment. Your error message shows that somehow, your site is trying to pass 'full_html' as the value, but it's expecting it to be in the format '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'.